How to merge two dataFrames of different lengths in R with partially matching name columns
I am hoping for a better way to write this code. I do not like the way I solved it and would like to see how other people might approach this. This took me several days to find the right resources and references to write this. I do not usually work in R so this was a challenge. I am a student and learning! I would appreciate someone with more experience than me weighing in.
I am trying to programmatically in R combine two data frames of different lengths based on partial name match without writing any new functions, and in a way that I can loop through the information easily if the input files grow.
I have two data frames.
df1 is two columns. The first column is names with a name structure that looks like :



Name
v1




name_Identifier1234
7005


name_987Identifier
6060



df2 has five columns the name column is structured as:



Name
val1
val2
val3
val4




name_Identifier1234_fee
100
200
300
400


name_Identifier1234_fie
101
202
303
404


name_987Identifier_fee
1000
2000
3000
4000


name_987Identifier_fie
1010
2020
3030
4040



There are more lines in df2 than in df1, I want to use a loop to add the values of df1 to a new column in df2 based on partial name match. If there is more than one partial match then add the value again to the new column in df2.
Here is how I did this:
smashList <- list()
# ne is all names in df1
for (ne in df1$name) {
  #using Grep to grab the name matches in df2
  partMatch <- grep(ne, df2$name, value = TRUE)
  #if there is anything contained in partMatch I can proceed 
  if (length(partMatch) > 0) {
    for (mn in partMatch) {
      
      matchedRows <- df2[df2$name == mn, ]
      
      # StoreColumns of df1 in the new variabe
      partMatch <- df1[df1$name == ne, ]
      
    
      combinedDF <- cbind(matchedRows, partMatch[, !names(partMatch) %in% "name"])
      
  
      smashList[[length(smashList) + 1]] <- combinedDF
    }
  }
}
# combine dfs so not just in list of dfs format, do r bind to combine all the tiny ones I have held there into one actual df
smashList <- do.call(rbind, smashList)
#rename column Name to something better for added name--- 
names(smashList)[6] <- "somethingBetter"

I have been trying different ways to solve this issue... I did find a solution and I will post it too with also some of my other attempts at answering.
These are partially/ half baked ideas of how to solve, didn't pan out, but perhaps shows you the direction I was thinking in.
#This was how I began working on my trying to get the two df Merged by partial name match  
namesLookinFor<- c(df1$name)
for (ne in namesLookinFor){
  if namesLookinFor in df2 and namesLookinFor in df1 
  Add value from df1 column v2 to df2 column totalHM
}


#loop only through the larger DF, then search in smaller DF, extract by index
#if name starts with name from df1 df add value from v2 of df1 to df2 df

namesLookinFor <- df1$name
#somethign is wrong as I am trying to pull the names to match here , keeps getting false 
for (ne in namesLookinFor) {
  if ne in df2$name 
  #matchingRows <- startsWith(ne, df2$name)
  #matchingRows <- which(startsWith(df2$name, ne))
  print(matchingRows)
}

#This is a slightly different approach but raises an error with left join, this is not able to match the partial names
namesLookinFor <- df1$name
for (ne in namesLookinFor){
  jOBandAll <- left_join(df2, df1, by = ne,"^")
  print(jOBandAll)
}

